# Redux Toolkit createSlice in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm learning Redux-Saga and everything works well with `{ configureStore, getDefaultMiddleware, createAction, createReducer }`. However, I cannot successfully implement `createSlice`.

My actions seem to be dispatched just fine (though I'm not sure since I have multiple Redux stores and placing `console.log` inside `createSlice` doesn't seem to work...). I just cannot get the `store` values - after dispatched action the relevant state value (initially `''`) becomes `undefined`. I did wrap my component inside `Provider` and all. Can someone enlighten me how does `createSlice` work? Thanks.

**RESOLVED** I had a bug somewhere else in my code, that's why the reducers weren't working proberly. BUT what I was asking about and what was causing my problems is this: actions passed to `createSlice` must be 'pure' functions, meaning: `(state, action) -> state`, nothing fancy. That's why I had to remove my fetching functions (`getData1` and `getData2`) from this `createSlice`.

ComponentWrapper returns this

```
<Provider store={toolkitCreateSliceStore}>
    <ReduxToolkitCreateSliceComponent />
</Provider>
```

Component (Buttons just dispatch actions)

```
class ReduxToolkitCreateSliceComponent extends React.Component {

    render () {
        return (
            <>
                <h2>
                    {this.props.data1}
                    {(this.props.data1!=='' && this.props.data2!=='') ? ', ' : ''}
                    {this.props.data2}
                </h2><br/>
                <h3>{this.props.message}</h3>
                <Button1 />
                <Button2 />
                <Button3 />
            </>
        );
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        data1: state.toolkitCreateSliceReducer.data1,
        data2: state.toolkitCreateSliceReducer.data2,
        message: state.toolkitCreateSliceReducer.message
    };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(ReduxToolkitCreateSliceComponent);
```

Redux Toolkit slice

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import axios from "axios";

const initialSliceState = {
    data1: '',
    data2: '',
    message: ''
};

const slice = createSlice({
    name: "slice",
    initialState: initialSliceState,
    reducers: {
        getData1: (state, action) => {
            return dispatch => {
                dispatch(loading1());
                return axios.get('http://localhost:8081/data1')
                    .then(function (response) {
                        if (response.status === 200) {
                            dispatch(setResponse1(response.data));
                        }
                    }).catch(error => dispatch(displayError1(error)));
            };
        },
        getData2: (state, action) => {
            return dispatch => {
                dispatch(loading2());
                return axios.get('http://localhost:8081/data2')
                    .then(function (response) {
                        if (response.status === 200) {
                            dispatch(setResponse2(response.data));
                        }
                    }).catch(error => dispatch(displayError2(error)));
            };
        },
        setResponse1: (state, action) => {
            state.data1 = action.payload;
            state.message = 'success';
        },
        setResponse2: (state, action) => {
            state.data2 = action.payload;
            state.message = 'success';
        },
        reset: (state, action) => {
            state.data1 = '';
            state.data2 = '';
            state.message = 'reset';
        },
        loading1: (state, action) => {
            state.message = 'loading';
        },
        loading2: (state, action) => {
            state.message = 'loading';
        },
        displayError1: (state, action) => {
            state.message = action.payload;;
        },
        displayError2: (state, action) => {
            state.message = action.payload;;
        }
    }
});

export const toolkitCreateSliceReducer = slice.reducer;

const { getData1, getData2, setResponse1, setResponse2, reset, loading1, loading2,
    displayError1, displayError2} = slice.actions;

export default slice;
```

Redux Toolkit store

```
const middleware = [
    ...getDefaultMiddleware()
];

const toolkitCreateSliceStore = configureStore({
    reducer: {
        toolkitCreateSliceReducer
    },
    middleware
});

export default toolkitCreateSliceStore;
```

Comment: I'm afraid the question isn't clear.  What specifically isn't working?

Comment: You're right. I just cannot get the `store` values - after dispatched action the relevant state value (initially `''`) becomes `undefined`.

Answer (score 4):

Your "reducers" are very wrong.

**A reducer must *never* have any side effects like AJAX calls**.

You've written some Redux "thunk" functions where your reducers should be:

```js
getData1: (state, action) => {
            return dispatch => {
                dispatch(loading1());
                return axios.get('http://localhost:8081/data1')
                    .then(function (response) {
                        if (response.status === 200) {
                            dispatch(setResponse1(response.data));
                        }
                    }).catch(error => dispatch(displayError1(error)));
            };
        },
```

This is a thunk, not a reducer.

A reducer would be something like:

```js
getData(state, action) {
  return action.payload;
}
```

I'd specifically recommend reading through our brand-new "Redux Essentials" core docs tutorial, which teaches beginners "how to use Redux, the right way", using our latest recommended tools and practices like Redux Toolkit.  It specifically covers how reducers should work, how to write reducers with `createSlice`, and how to write and use thunks alongside `createSlice`:

https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-1-overview-concepts

Answer (score 0):

If you're interested in creating async actions, let me recommend you an npm package that I created and use. It is [saga-toolkit](https://www.npmjs.com/package/saga-toolkit) that allows async functions to get resolved by sagas.

`slice.js`

```js
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import { createSagaAction  } from 'saga-toolkit'

const name = 'example'

const initialState = {
  result: null,
  loading: false,
  error: null,
}

export const fetchThings = createSagaAction(`${name}/fetchThings`)

const slice = createSlice({
  name,
  initialState,
  extraReducers: {
    [fetchThings.pending]: () => ({
      loading: true,
    }),
    [fetchThings.fulfilled]: ({ payload }) => ({
      result: payload,
      loading: false,
    }),
    [fetchThings.rejected]: ({ error }) => ({
      error,
      loading: false,
    }),
  },
})

export default slice.reducer
```

`sagas.js`

```js
import { call } from 'redux-saga/effects'
import { takeLatestAsync } from 'saga-toolkit'
import API from 'hyper-super-api'
import * as actions from './slice'

function* fetchThings() {
  const result = yield call(() => API.get('/things'))
  return result
}

export default [
  takeLatestAsync(actions.fetchThings.type, fetchThings),
]
```